# php redirect and google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, redirect

Hi I see there are some topics on this but can't really relate them to my question.
I have a domaina.com that I use for an email campaign.

This domain only has one page (index.php) and it redirects to my real website that is domainb.com

When I go into analytics I want to be able to see under referals that they came from domaina.com

There are so many ways of redirecting and I cant really figure out the right way to do it to make sure its looked at as a refereal by google analytics so I can use the data to analyse the outcome.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So what ways have you tried and what was wrong with each of your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I frankly do not think it's possible to set a referrer with a PHP redirect (AFAIK the referrer header is set by the browser, not by PHP).

However you can use campaign parameters and set the medium to "referrer", the source to domaina.com and campaign to "(not set)". So you would set your redirect url to:

```
http://www.domainb.com/?utm_source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domaina.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=(not%20set)
```

After GA evaluated the campaign paramters this should produce the result you want.

Comment: Hi. Does this require any other setup of campaign etc in Analytics?
The referal patch you give, I should be able to make php referal page on domaina.com using the URL you have posted. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes - as long as the campaign parameters are registered by the code on domainb.com this requires no further setup.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using PHP `header` to redirect to domainb.com then you can tell it to redirect to a certain page which is solely for recording Google Analytics, this page loads, and using a meta refresh or a javascript you can tell it to immediately forward on to the index.php page of DomainB.com.

For example:

```
     domainA.com/index.php:
---> redirects to domainB.com/redirect.php
---> loads the google analytics and a very bare minimum of HTML code including a meta or javascript redirect which then:
---> redirects todomainB.com/index.php
---> displays standard website.
```

This will then be tracked by Analytics on page visits, each visit to the redirect.php page can be judged as a visit FROM domainA.com

Comment: Hi I tried that. No luck
On domaina i added a php forward to rederect.php on domainb.
Then on domainb i edited redirect.php and added the following code to it:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.domainb">
however when i check analytics for today under pages. I search redirect.php and there are no hits. Do i do this correct?

Comment: @morten44, by default GA will show the referring domain (so you would look for domaina.com, not redirect.php). If you want to see the referring filename you need to select either "referral path" or "full referrer" as second dimension (this is true no mater if you use Martin's or my solution).

Comment: I was meaning you goto `GA --> (domainB) --> Behaviour --> Sitecontent --> landing Pages` and in this find `redirect.php` from which you can count the number of visitors to redirect.php. @morten44